# IIS hanging when running Active Reports, possibly splwow64.exe

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, performance, reporting

We have a Windows 2008 R2 web server running our web app on IIS and when running a particular page which generates a PDF (using Active Reports https://activereports.grapecity.com/) it takes between 1 and 2 minutes to generate the PDF document. The same application running on different servers does not experience the same issue, and also executing the same report from a console app on the same server completes in 2-3 seconds.

When this issue happens, I can see using IIS Worker Processes and then Resource Monitor->Analyze Wait Chain that the w3wp.exe process is waiting on splwow64.exe

[image: image of Resource Monitor]

I'm not sure how to proceed next. I've used procmon from SysInternals to watch the splwow64.exe process when this is happening but I can't see any out of the ordinary registry or file activity.

Is there anywhere else I can look to understand what might be causing the hang?